# Showing off finished projects

Tags: discussion, blog

Is there a place for us to show off the projects we finished with the help and knowledge from this site?

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like a great blog post! :)

Want us to set you up with a blog writer account?

Comment: +1 -- Blog post for SURE! :D